# Bottom screen margin to auto-expanding textbox

Tags: html, css, autosize

I have an auto-expanding text box based on [autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/).

While typing long text, the page scrolls down after cursor reaches bottom of the screen and I press return. This affects my design requirements that there should always be some space between the text and screen bottom.

Is there a way to achieve this space, preferably using only css?

```
<div class="container">
    <textarea id="id_text" name="text" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
```

Live example of the autosize textarea:
http://jsfiddle.net/ztb75su4/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a max-height element for the text-area:

```
#id_text {
    max-height:300px;
}
```

This simply means that it won't be able to extend past the amount of pixels you set. If the user wishes to enter more text than the space allows, they can scroll down.

Comment: I used auto-expanding textarea to avoid scroll bar in the textarea. Adding max-height produces it again.

Comment: Then I am unsure of exactly what you are going for? To avoid hitting screen-bottom you would have to set a max-height, otherwise it will hit the bottom, at least for any situation I can think of. Perhaps providing the exact circumstances you want to use this for might help?

Comment: I have updated the question to enhance its comprehensibility.